# what does "-std=standard" in gcc info page mean?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-mint

I want to know what C language standard is my current installation of gcc following by default. I ran `info gcc` and it gave `-std=standard`.

What does `-std=standard` mean?

I was expecting something like `-std=gnu11`

OS: linux mint 19.1
gcc version: 7.4.0,
gcc came pre-installed with the OS

I looked into online manual here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.4.0/gcc/Standards.html#C-Language

but I didn't find any default standard named "standard". Instead I found that it should be "gnu11"

info gcc response:

```
...
OPTIONS
   Option Summary
       Here is a summary of all the options, grouped by type.  Explanations
       are in the following sections.

       Overall Options
           -c  -S  -E  -o file  -x language -v  -###  --help[=class[,...]]
           --target-help  --version -pass-exit-codes  -pipe  -specs=file
           -wrapper @file  -fplugin=file  -fplugin-arg-name=arg
           -fdump-ada-spec[-slim]  -fada-spec-parent=unit  -fdump-go-spec=file

       C Language Options
           -ansi  -std=standard  -fgnu89-inline
           -fpermitted-flt-eval-methods=standard -aux-info filename
           -fallow-parameterless-variadic-functions -fno-asm 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "standard" is in a cursive font. It's a template, it's not a "default gcc standard gcc uses by default", it's a template to be filled by the user with available option, the word "standard" stands there for `gnu11` or `c11` or for the standard you want to specify.

The same is with -fpermitted-flt-eval-methods=*standard* or -fno-builtin-*function*. You should specify the *function* that gcc should not use builtin for. This is a list of available options for C language in gcc, not list of default options gcc uses.

You can find the standard gcc is using by inspecting `__STDC_VERSION__` macro. Or check the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards). Quoting the link, for gcc 7.2.0:

> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu11.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found __STDC_VERSION__ to be 201112L, which I suppose means C11 standards. I used `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` command.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of `-std=standard`, `standard` is meant to represent one of the values listed in the [Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options). It isn't meant to literally be the string `standard`; that results in an error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=standard’
```